# problem with sending email ... goes back to previous activity

Tags: android, email

I have 2 activities- A and B. I have a list on activity A and if I click on it, it goes to activity B. On activity B, I have a button for sharing email with the following code :

```
shareEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailButton);

    shareEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("!!! email !!!");


         Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             emailIntent.setType("text/html");


         emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "sharing something interesting" );
         emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sharing something interesting !!" );

         //hideKeyboard();

         activityB.this.startActivity(emailIntent);


        }
    });
```

Now, when I send an email, the email window closes and activity B also closes. I am not sure why that is happening. Any hints ? Thanks.

logcat output:

```
09-20 04:14:05.969: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) }
09-20 04:14:06.279: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.email/.activity.MessageCompose (has extras) }
09-20 04:14:06.699: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2790): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7815 objects / 586592 bytes in 128ms
09-20 04:14:12.099: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Displayed activity com.android.email/.activity.MessageCompose: 5794 ms (total 6097 ms)
09-20 04:14:18.158: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2768): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4016 objects / 308824 bytes in 217ms
09-20 04:14:19.098: WARN/InputManagerService(60): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44e7e000 (uid=10025 pid=2790)
09-20 04:14:19.128: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(2790): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-20 04:14:19.709: DEBUG/webviewglue(2790): nativeDestroy view: 0x374c08
09-20 04:14:21.339: DEBUG/dalvikvm(60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10068 objects / 491696 bytes in 207ms
09-20 04:14:24.739: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2696): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1576 objects / 82792 bytes in 123ms
09-20 04:14:29.849: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2790): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5335 objects / 279624 bytes in 224ms
```

Comment: @CapDroid : no error but the output is attached with the question!

Comment: Ohhh did you registerd in Email app and try to use startActivityForResult

Answer (score 0):

you have to use intent.crateChoose in start activity. now use the edited code.

```
shareEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailButton);

    shareEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("!!! email !!!");


         Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             emailIntent.setType("text/html");


         emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "sharing something interesting" );
         emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sharing something interesting !!" );

         //hideKeyboard();

         activityB.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Sending Mail..."));


        }
    });
```